# Can we automatically set VM variable while building java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

While running Java application I need to set some VM like

`-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc:project}\lib;${env_var:‌​PATH}`.

Its working fine, but when I change the system, I have to set it again in Eclipse environment.

Is there any way I can do this automatically (like ant build/ scripting) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the Java library path from a Java task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159333/how-do-i-set-the-java-library-path-from-a-java-task)

Comment: You can set it in ant build, or a script, or windows path https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp

Comment: You could modify eclipse.ini and use it for all environments.